# How to get a simple stream of string using ServiceStack Grpc?

Tags: c#, servicestack, grpc

fighting with the ServiceStack library since a while to get a basic "stream" of string to work in C#.

In short, I'm trying to replicate the basic example from "native" gRPC.

**Proto buf**

```
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

**Server**

```
public override async Task SayHello(HelloRequest request, IServerStreamWriter<HelloReply> responseStream,                                            ServerCallContext context)
    {
        foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
        {
            await responseStream.WriteAsync(new HelloReply
            {
                Message = $"Hello {request.Name} {x}"
            });

            await Task.Delay(200);
        }
    }
```

**Client**

```
var replies = client.SayHello(new HelloRequest { Name = "Laurent" });

await foreach (var reply in replies.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reply.Message);
}
```

Then with the ServiceStack library, I'm not able to get the server piece done correctly. I always get a message telling me my function 'SayHello' isn't defined.

Let me know, thx !

Answer (score 3):

[ServiceStack gRPC](https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc) implementation adopts a [code-first implementation where your existing ServiceStack Services](https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc#servicestack-services-are-grpc-services) can be called from gRPC endpoints.

So instead of manually authoring a `.proto` file you would instead create Services using [standard Request / Response DTOs](https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc#servicestack-services-are-grpc-services) and `Service` implementation for normal Request/Reply gRPC Services.

For [Server Stream gRPC Services](https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc#server-stream-grpc-services) you would need to implement [IStreamService](https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc#implementing-server-stream-services) interface in addition to inheriting from ServiceStack's `Service` base class.

An example of this is covered in [Implementing Server Stream Services](https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc#implementing-server-stream-services) in the docs:

```
public class StreamFileService : Service, IStreamService<StreamFiles,FileContent>
{
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<FileContent> Stream(StreamFiles request, 
        CancellationToken cancel = default)
    {
        var i = 0;
        var paths = request.Paths ?? TypeConstants.EmptyStringList;
        while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var file = VirtualFileSources.GetFile(paths[i]);
            var bytes = file?.GetBytesContentsAsBytes();
            var to = file != null
                ? new FileContent {
                    Name = file.Name,
                    Type = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(file.Extension),
                    Body = bytes,
                    Length = bytes.Length,
                }
                : new FileContent {
                    Name = paths[i],
                    ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus {
                        ErrorCode = nameof(HttpStatusCode.NotFound),
                        Message = "File does not exist",
                    }
                };

            yield return to;

            if (++i >= paths.Count)
                yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

You would also need to register your **Stream Service** implementation in `RegisterServices`:

```
Plugins.Add(new GrpcFeature(App) {
    RegisterServices = {
        typeof(StreamFileService)
    }
});
```

If you're using the [smart C# generic gRPC Service Client](https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc-generic) you can avoid `.proto` descriptors and protoc generated classes entirely as you can reuse the Server DTOs in your [ServiceModel project](https://docs.servicestack.net/physical-project-structure#servicemodel-project) to enable an end-to-end API without code-gen:

```
var request = new StreamFiles {
    Paths = new List<string> {
        "/js/ss-utils.js",
        "/js/hot-loader.js",
        "/js/not-exists.js",
        "/js/hot-fileloader.js",
    }
};

var files = new List<FileContent>();
await foreach (var file in client.StreamAsync(request))
{
    files.Add(file);
}
```

An alternative to sharing your **ServiceModel.dll** you can use [C# Add ServiceStack Reference](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-add-servicestack-reference) to generate your C# DTOs on the client.

For [protoc generated clients](https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc#protoc-generated-clients) you can use the [x dotnet tool](https://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-tool) to [Generate protoc Dart gRPC Client](https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc-dart#generate-protoc-dart-grpc-client)

```
$ x proto-dart https://todoworld.servicestack.net -out lib
```

Where you can use the `serverStreamFiles` API stubs to invoke the server stream Service:

```
var stream = client.serverStreamFiles(StreamFiles()..paths.addAll([
  '/js/ss-utils.js',
  '/js/hot-loader.js',
  '/js/hot-fileloader.js',
]));

await for (var file in stream) {
  var text = utf8.decode(file.body);
  print('FILE ${file.name} (${file.length}): ${text.substring(0, text.length < 50 ? text.length : 50)} ...');
}
```

The [todo-world/clients](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/todo-world/tree/master/src/clients) repo contains a number of gRPC test examples in different langauges.

Comment: Hi Mytz,
thx for your answer.  This was a bit over-complicated for my experience with Grpc in C#, but I was finally able to get that to work. I end up, as you suggested, to remove the proto-file and use the exemple in the 2nd project (C# generic) from Service Stack ToDoWorld example.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, here's what I end up doing as a simple POC of a stream, if this can help anyone else. No more proto-file either !

**Client Program.cs :**

```
        private async static Task GetBotStream()
        {
            var res = client.StreamAsync(new BotStreamRequest { });

            await foreach (var textReceived in res)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(textReceived.Result);
            }
        }
```

**Client dtos.cs**

```
   [DataContract]
    public partial class BotStreamRequest : IReturn<BotStreamReply>
    {
    }

    [DataContract]
    public partial class BotStreamReply
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public virtual string Result { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public virtual ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

**Server Program.cs**

```
        public async IAsyncEnumerable<BotStreamReply> Stream(BotStreamRequest request, [EnumeratorCancellation]CancellationToken cancel = default)
        {
            foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
            {
                yield return new BotStreamReply { Result = $"My stream {x}" };
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you possibly give an example of how the Stream method is invoked from the request? its a little unclear how the request triggers the stream such that the request results in the user receiving more than 1 response i.e do you need an await inside the botstreamrequest class or how exactly is it transformed? any help would be great